# Complex code in AsyncTask freeze progressBar

Tags: android-asynctask

I have a complex code in AsyncTask, which makes alot of I / O on SQLite and heavy calculation. This piece of code is very long and that's why I did not copy it here. When my code is commented AsyncTask works very well and update progress bar correctly, but with my code, the progress bar is frozen until at the end of my code.
Can anyone give me recommendations to respect, to write the program like mine with of course, a worker thread and a progress bar that works well?
I finished my project. in phase of development, I had no problem. but in phase testing with real data I am confronted with this problem. It's been three days that I read on a AsyncTask discussed on this forum but neither my help and I do not know what to do. I also frozen.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved.
Apparently my code uses alot of CPU time and does not leave enough time for UIThread to update  the screen.
So I set the portion of code that accede SQLite in another thread using a Handler and a CountDownLatch with 10ms delay to start the thread. and this delay allows android has to release time for UIThread to refresh. this way, publishProgress started working. Now I wonder if it's a good solution.